# hiding keystore password from process list

Tags: java, ssl, jmx, keystore

I have a Linux server and a java application. I am using Java 1.7 to run this application. I want to enable JMX for monitoring purposes. The JMX connection should be secured by SSL. So far so easy.

My problem: How do I tell the jvm the keystore-password in a secure way? So far the ssl connection only works if I pass the password over the command line parameter "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypwd". It seems that the password must be set on initialising of the jvm.

If I am looking at the process list (ps -ef) on the console I can see my java process - but with all the command line parameters. So my keystore password is listed in plain text for everyone who can list the active processes (eg over a snmp agent). How can I hide the password from the process list?

I have tried to use a config file (com.sun.management.config.file). It works well for all jmx specific parameters. But my password is ignored.

Is providing the password in a command line parameter in plain text realy the only way?

Yes - I know that Java 1.7 ist out of service. If Java 1.8 actualy fixes this problem I will change immediatly.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Just a suggestion but can you cat the password from a file that is only readable by the JVM (or JMX) User or Group.

Comment: I would have to cat the password from the startscript. Therefore the password itself is shown in the process list - not the cat command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "mypwd")` *before* you use any of the SSL functionality in your program it should work. That means you should aim to set it as early after `main` has been called as you can. You can load your own properties file before if you like (readable only by the user running the JVM), where the password can be stored.

---

**Update**

System properties needed for management can also be set in a configuration file. From [Monitoring and Management Using JMX Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdevf):

> You can set out-of-the-box monitoring and management properties in a
>   configuration file or on the command line. Properties specified on the
>   command line override properties in a configuration file. The default
>   location for the configuration file is
>   *JRE_HOME*`/lib/management/management.properties`. The Java VM reads this
>   file if either of the command-line properties
>   `com.sun.management.jmxremote` or `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` are
>   set.

This documentation is for Java 1.8, but I guess the same applies to Java 1.7. If not, I guess you have to switch as you suggested.

Comment: As I mentioned above I am trying to use JMX with SSL. JMX is activated on startup of the JVM. Setting the system property from anywhere in the main function comes AFTER activating SSL for JMX.

Comment: Bingo! You can pass the following parameter to your vm: -Dcom.sun.management.config.file=<file>. In this file you can set the property com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.config.file=<file>. And finally in this file you can set the properties javax.net.ssl.keyStore=file and javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<pwd>. If you know where to look the documentation is rather good. Unfortunally it is well hidden...

Comment: OK - it's a little bit simpler. Just pass the parameter -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.config.file=<file> directly to the vm. No need for the management.properties file.

Comment: @erwrock After good 5 years. Of course documentation mentions that one can use property files on the command line. For some reason they do not seem to work for me. Did they work for you?

Comment: @mvsagar: yes - the property file work quite fine for me. we are using them in different java services.

Comment: @erwrock, thanks for your update. They partially work for me. SSL property file works only for JMX server(agent) but it does not work for JMX client. I posed question in SO but no replies so far. May be I am doing something wrong. Here is the link for my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60239005/ssl-propertyconfiguration-files-on-a-jmx-agent-and-jmx-client-command-lines-ma  I am using jdk 1.8.0_221.

Comment: without having it checked:  theres a difference between jmx server and client. the jmx server is started when the jvm is started. therefore all properties must be provided at startup - either als system property or as property file. the jmx client is completly different: the connection to the server is started when "the java bytecode tells it so to the jvm". so your program has full control. you can choose whatever path to provide the credentials as you wish and store them into the right properties at runtime. just create a property-file and read from it!

Comment: @erwrock, as I lost hope of making the configuration files work after spending considerable time, I modified jmx server and client programs to set properties from inside the Java programs and they are working! Now I have full control over passwords. I encrypt passwords in env variables, read from programs, decrypt and set properties. So passwords are no more visible!