# Java: Obfuscate keystore password

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I have spent almost a day searching on google, forums with all combinations and permutations of queries but still no luck, so here i am with a question again.

I am mentioning the keystore password under arguments in weblogic. But when the server is running, i can see in the process that the keystore password is visible. My question is, is there a way to store the password in a file and have that file mentioned in the arguments.

Below are the arguments

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=<PATH_TO_JKS>
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<PASSWORD>
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks
```

I am using JDK8 and weblogic 12c. I do not want to rely on the keystore provided by weblogic.

The link [hiding keystore password from process list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011428/hiding-keystore-password-from-process-list/32011693#32011693) seem to answer the question, but when i tried it didnt work as expected. The error says "Password file not found". Also tried the approach mentioned in the comment section as well, but no luck. Help please.

Comment: Who are you trying to protect the password from? Who are you trying to protect the keystore from?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation below: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/security/ConfigureKeystoresAndSSL.html
The entries "Custom Identity Keystore Passphrase" & "Custom Trust Keystore Passphrase" should be set accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide an encrypted value to a user along with its key material and prevent the user from decoding it except when you want them to. If you provide the password to the user then the user has the password. End of story.

If the client can decode a value to plaintext in one context, then the client can decode it to plaintext in ANY context.

You can slow them down but not stop them.